# CloudQueueMessage.GetMessagesAsync hangs whilst synchronous version doesn't

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm running into some tough to explain oddities when trying to retrieve messages from my local storage queues. I'm fairly sure this isn't happening in production using actual Azure queues.

The line in particular causing this issue is:

```
msgs = await priorityQueue.GetMessagesAsync(Settings.NumberOfMessagesToGet, visibilityTimeSpan, null, null);
```

Which will just do nothing and doesn't seem to ever return. However, replacing it with:

```
msgs = priorityQueue.GetMessages(Settings.NumberOfMessagesToGet, visibilityTimeSpan, null, null);
```

Returns back once it's done and seems fine.

Am I using the await here right? Any ideas why this isn't working?

I'm using the Windows Azure SDK 2.8, with the Windows Azure Storage Emulator 4.2.0.0, in case it gives any clues.

Comment: Are you calling `Result` or `Wait` further up your call stack?

Comment: Do you mean on that returned task? I thought awaiting a task meant you didn't have to call result. Or do you mean for something else?

Comment: You totally *should* be using `await` - all the way up. I'm wondering if your local code has a `Result` or `Wait` in it that isn't in your production code.

Comment: I'm of course going to say "but of course we are!", but I probably should check. I want to avoid posting reems of code here, I've been got for that one before.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Storage Queues sample on GitHub demonstrates how to use async patterns with the .NET Client library from a console application:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-queue-dotnet-getting-started

Notice that at the top level of the program, the "Wait()" method is used:

```
ProcessBatchOfMessagesAsync(queue).Wait();
```